# How to catch the output, error and status code in python 2.7 SubProcess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to execute a `bash` command using `python` and what I need is to catch all the `output`, `error` and the `status_code` of the final execution.

This is what I have tried:

```
 p = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-o', 'https://lb.*:2379'], stdin=open(constants.MANIFEST_PATH))
```

when i execute this, it gives the output even without printing it.

So I tried something like this.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['grep', '-o', 'https://lb.*:2379'], stdin=open(constants.MANIFEST_PATH))
output, err = p.communicate(b"input data that is passed to subprocess' stdin")
print(output)
print(err)
print(p.returncode)
```

this gives the below output:

```
https://lb-etcd.banu12.eu-west-1.dev:2379
None
None
0
```

It prints the output but it never catched by the `output` variable. If any errors, not even to `err` variable.

How can I make this work?

And in case you need, `constants.MANIFEST_PATH` looks like below:

```
MANIFEST_PATH = "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml"
```

Can someone help me to grab all **output**(if exists), **error**(if exists) and the **return code**

Comment: May I ask why you're using Python 2?

Comment: I am running these command inside a `kubernetes` cluster which I have installed `python 2.7`. I can't just upgrade to newest version.

Comment: _I can't just upgrade to newest version._ I wouldn't know, I'm not familiar with Kubernetes lol Good luck!

Comment: Do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: so kube-apiserver.yaml is the file are you trying grep ??